# Factory pattern C# with autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, factory-pattern

I would like to adapt the factory pattern (from wikipedia) using autofac :

```
/IVSR:Factory Pattern
//Empty vocabulary of Actual object
public interface IPeople
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Villagers : IPeople
{
    #region IPeople Members

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Village Guy";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class CityPeople : IPeople
{
    #region IPeople Members

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "City Guy";
    }

    #endregion
}

public enum PeopleType
{
    RURAL,
    URBAN
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of Factory - Used to create objects
/// </summary>
public class Factory
{
    public IPeople GetPeople(PeopleType type)
    {
        IPeople people = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case PeopleType.RURAL :
                people = new Villagers();
                break;
            case PeopleType.URBAN:
                people = new CityPeople();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return people;
    }
}
```

In addition, classes implementing IPeople should benefits of dependency injection, for example CityPeople constructor should have a IRepository injected, Villagers should have an IService injected, and so on ...

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: of course I've already followed this tutorial, I don't undestand how I can register a type depending of a condition

Comment: @nvoigt That basic docs doesn't cover OP's specific scenario. His factory needs to return types based on parameter.

Comment: Before doing anything else, singularise your class and variable names; they are not collections, they are individuals.

Comment: I've already seen this answer too, but the problem is that there are explicit new. Why using new with autofac ? How can I do the specific dependy injection with my providers and services ?

Comment: It's a shame this was closed, since the answer to the duplicate question is slightly different, and I have an answer which avoids the use of a switch statement... If you ask the question again but specify that you want to avoid the use of a switch statement, I could answer it. The answer uses "Keyed Services".

Comment: Thanks, Keyed services seems very good for my need. Regards

Comment: Also look at [Metadata](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html). I've solved the same problem  using metadata.